# Что случилось с импортами ? intelij idea

Tags: java, импорт, ant, intelij

в какой то момент часть импортов как будто отвалилась и идея никак не может их разрешить. Соответственно идея не может предлагать методы классов импорты которых отвалились. При этом проект билдится и запускается как надо, из чего я делаю вывод, что проблема именно в конфиге самой идеи, но понять в чем именно проблема никак не могу. Мне бы помогла хотя бы подсказка в какую сторону копать.

Использую на проекте Ant. Встречал похожую проблему на проекте с maven, там помогало просто вызвать перезагрузку всех проектов через мейвен меню.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Скорее всего проблема связана не с системой сборки, а с самой IDE. Встречал подобное в т.ч. с gradle. Обычно помогает следующее - удаление из проекта папок/файлов IDE и системы сборки и открытие проекта заново, с указанием папки. Не помню как это в ant устроено, но для gradle надо удалять папки build (у вас скорее всего они тоже есть), а также папку `.idea` - в ней в т.ч. есть файлы сопоставления подключённых либ (вроде xml файл с названием типа `libraries`). Также стоит в IDEA `Invalidate Caches and restart` выполнить.